# SQL query to use .split() and .include(

Tags: sql, node.js, split, include, azure-cosmosdb

I have the below SQL query for my Azure Cosmos DB

```
SELECT distinct c.id1,stuff.id2,e.id3 FROM c
join stuff in c.stuff
join d in stuff.a.b.c.d
join e in  d.e
where ARRAY_CONTAINS(e.classes,{name:"${searchWord}"},true)
```

The issue I am having is that this only returns exact `name` matches.

What I am trying to do is find any `name` that includes the `searchWord` similar to `classes.name.split(' ').includes(searchWord)` - for example return "green cup" when `searchWord == cup`.
In Node it would be:

```
   var splice = name.split(' ');
   if(splice.includes(searchWord))
```

Is someone able to help clear up where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you that you want to implement a function similar to `LIKE` in Cosmos DB SQL API. The keyword for `LIKE` is `CONTAINS` here. If you had a document with a `firstName` property and you wanted to filter on the name `'bob'` you would use it in a query this way:

```
"SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(c.firstName, 'bob')"
```

Please try below sql:

```
SELECT distinct c.id1,stuff.id2,e.id3 FROM c
join stuff in c.stuff
join d in stuff.a.b.c.d
join e in  d.e
join class in e.classes
where contains(class.name,"trees")
```

### Updated Answer

I got your idea. But sorry, there is no such keyword or function like you said in cosmos db currently. So, I don't think you can rely entirely on sql. You can try the combination of sql and code, which eliminates a lot of loops and reduces the pressure on the code, which can also meet your individual needs.

In addition, you could submit [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to ask Azure Cosmos DB Team to support such function in the future.

Comment: The issue here is that this returns `trees` even if I search `re` or `tre`. This has added the `includes` part but without adding the `.split(' ')` functionality. Is there a way to somehow add `where ARRAY_CONTAINS(class.name.split(' '), "trees")`? To remind you of the original functionality, I `.split(' ')` and then `.include()` which means I am looking for whole word matches within `name`

Comment: Is there not a way perhaps to join/manipulate `class.name` into an individual words array and search that?

Comment: Would something like this help solve - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 ?

Comment: @JDT However like I said, all the supported keywords are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#string-functions. As I know,cosmos db sql is differs with T-SQL. It has it's own limitation(of course,it will be gradually improved )

Comment: @JDT No such split function in cosmos db sql currently. You could try to give feedback to ask Azure Cosmos DB Team to add such function. If you think pressure in code is too heavy, you could use stored procedure to do some logic process. It runs on the cosmos db server side and could also reduces your client pressure.

Comment: I am not familiar with stored procedure, would stored procedure be beneficial over just pulling `SELECT * FROM root r` into an array and using node to `for loop` my way down as per my original solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180327/discussion-between-jay-gong-and-jdt).

Comment: @JDT If you think my answer helps you,you could mark it for others' reference.Thanks a lot!